# Why do I need to specify the object type twice?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

Give this method signature that's an extension of a protocol:

```swift
loadObjectFromDB<T: DBObject>(_ db: ALBNoSQLDB, for key: String, queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) -> DBCommandToken?
```

Why can't I call it like this? (Category is a struct that adheres to the protocol)

```swift
let token = Category.loadObjectFromDB(db, for categoryKey) { (category) in
    // use category object
}
```

I get a compilation error saying generic parameter T could not be inferred and I have to specify the type again in what is in the execution block:

```
let token = Category.loadObjectFromDB(db, for categoryKey) { (category: Category) in
    // use category object
}
```

Comment: Because the method is written to load any `DBObject` type even if it is called on `Category`. I feel the method declaration is not written well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `T`'s only constraint is that it's a `DBObject`, the compiler doesn't know anything else about it. If it was constrained to `Self` instead, then you wouldn't have to explicitly state the type.